# Zsh bad substitution error in zshrc

Tags: zsh

I have this in my .zhsrc file:

```
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-of-line
```

Pressing Home on my keyboard does seem to trigger going to the beggining of line, so it seems to work, however whenever I edit the .zshrc in vim and save it SyntasticCheck zsh reports a "bad substitution" error.

Is this an error on my part or a bug in the syntax checker?

### Edit in response to comment:

No I do not get an error when Zsh starts and yes Syntastic checker says the error is on that line.

```
$ sed -n /Home/l .zshrc
key[Home]=${terminfo[khome]}$
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-o\
f-line$
```

### EDIT 2. Output of zsh -vn .zshrc

I cleaned up my .zshrc file to this:

```
echo OK
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-of-line
echo OK2
```

When I start my shell I see both OK and OK2, no errors show. But here's the output of zsh -vn .zshrc

```
# /etc/zsh/zshenv: system-wide .zshenv file for zsh(1).
#
# This file is sourced on all invocations of the shell.
# If the -f flag is present or if the NO_RCS option is
# set within this file, all other initialization files
# are skipped.
#
# This file should contain commands to set the command
# search path, plus other important environment variables.
# This file should not contain commands that produce
# output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.
#
# Global Order: zshenv, zprofile, zshrc, zlogin

if [[ -z "$PATH" || "$PATH" == "/bin:/usr/bin" ]]
then
        export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games"
fi
echo OK
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-of-line
.zshrc:2: bad substitution
```

### Edit 3

Version: zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: That line is valid zsh syntax. Probably the error, if any is on some other line. Is it only SyntasticCheck that reports an error, or do you get the error as well when `zsh` starts? Does it give a line number for the error? Does that point to that very line?

Comment: You could get that message if there were invisible characters inside those `${...}`. What's the output of `sed -n /Home/l .zshrc`?

Comment: AFAICT, syntastic uses `zsh -n` on the file to check the syntax. Do you get the same error with `zsh -n .zshrc`?

Comment: Yes, I do: `zsh -n .zshrc \n .zshrc:73: bad substitution`

Comment: And it's OK with `zsh .zshrc`? What about `zsh -vn .zshrc`? Is it possible that the parsing of some earlier code relies on some option having been turned on before like extendedglob (which wouldn't be done with `zsh -n`)

Comment: oh yeah, I do have `extendedglob` - is that the cause of this

Comment: I can't think of a case where that could be a problem. I'm trying to imagine a scenario where `zsh -n` would fail while `zsh` doesn't. What I'm thinking is some part of your code that uses a syntax that is not understood by default, but is understood because a command earlier changes the parsing behaviour. I wouldn't expect your ~/.zshrc to use any glob. That could also be an alias.

Comment: Here's the top bit from the output of `zsh -vn .zshrc` https://pastebin.com/S4rTqJyV (it sources `.zshrc.conf` but this file only has one line in it, `PS1_HOST_COLOUR=green`)

Comment: Can you post the whole output of `zsh -vn`? You can remove sensible parts so long as `zsh -n` on that output still triggers the error.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, please see edited question

Comment: OK, I had hoped the problem was in earlier code and the line number was incorrectly reported. It looks more like it's a bug in your particular version of zsh. I can't reproduce with 5.1.1, 5.3.1, 4.3.10. What's your version?

Comment: zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can reproduce with 5.0.5 as well. `zsh -nc '${a[1]}'` is enough to reproduce it. Looks like it was a regression at some point (as it worked with older versions) and it has been fixed later on. If you want, you could play with `git bisect` to see when it was introduced and when it was fixed again.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all your help, I opened this question thinking it was going to be something stupid I'd done. Happy to close it now. If you want to submit an answer saying "this was a bug, is fixed" I'll accept it, so that anyone else finding it (2 upvotes) can see what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a bug in some older versions of `zsh` fixed in 5.1. Changelog:

> 2015-07-15  Barton E. Schaefer
>
> - 35799: Src/params.c: with NO_EXEC, parse parameter subscript
>        expressions to correctly balance enclosing braces, but do not
>        perform the subscripting

after [it was reported](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg01723.html) the same day.

With those versions, it can be reproduced with:

```
$ zsh -nc '${a[1]}'
zsh:1: bad substitution
```

According to `git bisect`, the bug was introduced in 2011 in [a fix to a similar issue for associative arrays](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00056.html) in commit [dfc26195c916d54163a3f0dd2eb159db2d974569](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/dfc26195c916d54163a3f0dd2eb159db2d974569), starting with version zsh-4.3.12

More generally, `zsh -n` (or `anyshell -n`) is quite limited in its ability to lint code as since it's not running the code, it can't do much in areas where the way some code is evaluated depends on some code that was run beforehand.

For instance `${a[1+]}` is invalid for an array, but OK for a hash. Without knowing which `zsh -n` just doesn't complain.

It can also give false positives like in:

```
alias aslongas=while
aslongas whatever; do
  something
done
```

Where it complains about that unexpected `do` because it has not acknowledged `aslongas` as an alias for `while`.